# How can I change my AngularJS service to use Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have this service:

```
app.factory('utilityService', [
    '$http',
    '$angularCacheFactory',
    utilityService
]);

function utilityService(
    $http,
    $angularCacheFactory
    ) {

    var factory = {};

    factory.rowClicked = function ($index, collection) {
        var row = collection[$index];
        if (row.current) {
            row.current = false;
            return null;
        } else {
            collection.forEach(function (object) {
                object.current = false;
            });
            row.current = true;
            return $index;
        }
    };

    factory.isArrayAndNotEmpty = function (theArray) {
        var rc = typeof theArray !== 'undefined' && theArray.length > 0;
        return rc;
    };


    return factory;

}
```

Typescript appears to recognize everything okay until it comes to the rowClicked (and all the other functions which I didn't show here to save space). For these it gives the message:

```
factory.rowClicked

The property rowClicked does not exist on value of type '{}'
```

Comment: Why not just use a class : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM&hd=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var factory = {};
```

TypeScript infers the type of `factory` from its initializer. Here, you've said that `factory` has no members, so any attempt to read or write a property on it is going to fail.

You could simply change the type of `factory` to be `any`:

```
var factory: any = {};
```

This will make it valid to read or write any property of `factory`, but that might be too permissive. You could also write out the type of it:

```
var factory: {
    rowClicked($index, collection);
} = <any>{};
```

If you have types for `$index` and `collection`, you could improve the type further:

```
var factory: {
    rowClicked($index: MyIndexService, collection: MyRowCollectionType);
} = <any>{};
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed explanation. Can you tell me what the = <any>{}; means at the end of your definition for factory?

Comment: Because `{}` lacks the members of the declared type, it has to be "casted" to `any` to be assigned to the variable

Comment: Thanks and now I understand. I updated my answer to show you what I now have. One last question. Could I combine definition "rowClicked($index, collection);", the actual function definition and the return all into one so I don't even need to use the word "factory" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript classes for services and you will get greater TypeSafety without needing TypeAssertions (or manual interfaces).

You will need to use `angular.service` instead of `angular.factory`. Reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM&hd=1